# How to position images (with text underneath) on one row?

Tags: html, css

How can I position 11 images (with text underneath each) in the same row? Here's a slightly simplified version of my existing code:

```css
.a {
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    
-moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1s;
    -moz-animation-name: blink;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
}

.b {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="group-10" class="col-md-12">
    <img class="a" src="img/...png"><span class="b">A</span>
    <img class="a" src="img/...png"><span class="b">A</span>
    <img class="a" src="img/...png"><span class="b">A</span>
    <img class="a" src="img/...png"><span class="b">A</span>
    <img class="a" src="img/...png"><span class="b">A</span>
    <img class="a" src="img/...png"><span class="b">A</span>
    <img class="a" src="img/...png"><span class="b">A</span>
    <img class="a" src="img/...png"><span class="b">A</span>
    <img class="a" src="img/...png"><span class="b">A</span>
    <img class="a" src="img/...png"><span class="b">A</span>
    <img class="a" src="img/...png"><span class="b">A</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Row or column? Currently they are in a row.

Comment: I am trying to position them in a row, and not they are currently in a column.

Comment: they're in a row - see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0m04sfc7/

Comment: @StillMoJo width: 90px; not  widht: 90px;

Comment: Based on your one class name, I'd assume you are using Bootstrap?

Comment: @StillMoJo invalid class names "1" and  "2"

Comment: Check out the image and tell me again that they are in a row
http://i58.tinypic.com/2hqe3yv.jpg

Comment: don't mind the classes 1 and 2 imagine 1 = picture, 2 = text. The class is not the problem atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your elements and set the wrapper to be `inline-block`.

```css
.ab {
    display: inline-block;
}
.a {
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

-moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1s;
    -moz-animation-name: blink;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
}

.b {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="group-10" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="ab">
        <img class="a" src="img/...png"/><span class="b">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ab">
        <img class="a" src="img/...png"/><span class="b">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ab">
        <img class="a" src="img/...png"/><span class="b">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ab">
        <img class="a" src="img/...png"/><span class="b">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ab">
        <img class="a" src="img/...png"/><span class="b">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ab">
        <img class="a" src="img/...png"/><span class="b">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ab">
        <img class="a" src="img/...png"/><span class="b">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ab">
        <img class="a" src="img/...png"/><span class="b">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ab">
        <img class="a" src="img/...png"/><span class="b">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ab">
        <img class="a" src="img/...png"/><span class="b">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ab">
        <img class="a" src="img/...png"/><span class="b">A</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But when I replace it as you say, the text is positioned on the right side of the image, not below as I want.

Comment: So you want each set of image and text to flow left to right?

Comment: Text should flow below each image

Comment: @StillMoJo Updated my answer

Comment: @StillMoJo please view this http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html to learn how bootstrap grids works. no floats no inline blocks;

Comment: adding a class to each picture really solved my problem.
Best Regards,
StillMoJo!

Comment: @StillMoJo i told you this a long time ago. you persist in using numbers for class names. if u changed it to 'a3' it would've worked too. moral of the story: Listen to good advice

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try : -

```
.col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

img {
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

-moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1s;
    -moz-animation-name: blink;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
}

span {
   float: left; 
}
```

Your class names are causing the problem `1` and `2`. I would advise using a different class name for the `img` and `span`.

Comment: in my HTML they are called "pic1" and "text1" I made them here 1 and 2 to be easyer for understanding what I want to do.

Comment: @StillMoJo - positioned like what?

Answer (score 0):

@StillMoJo class names cannot start with a number, add a letter in front of them, like A1, B2, etc..
Also, correct the widht to width

Comment: They can start with a number, you can escape them like `.\31`

Comment: so you escape them with \3 not \, did not know that so kudos to you.